# Add lightning component action to related list

Tags: lightning, custom-button, related-list, component

I need some help please! I know something can be done, I just can't find the answer to this.
I have these two objects Case (parent) and Party Document (child). One of my team's developers has created a lightning component action in Buttons, Links, and Actions in obj. manager for Party Document and they now need to show the action on the Party Document related list on Case, but I can't seem to figure that one out. You'll see in the image, when we click the down arrow, that's where we want it to show. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you are looking for is not a supported feature in Lightning at the moment (see idea link below). This is a painful limitation on the platform, but is not totally hopeless as you can still create list buttons and add to your lightning pages. The limitation here is that you have to decide whether to send the user to a URL, run some Javascript, or send them to a VF page.

Another option would be to rebuild the related list as an LWC, or I've seen others simply add a button just above the related list - not exactly elegant, but it does the trick.

Of course, take a look on the AppExchange before building anything. There are several free apps which provide additional customization for your related lists!

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003TXFQA2

[image: List Button Reference]